# Finding number of points in a bounded set when number of points in the unbounded set are known.

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-variables

Consider a random distribution of points in a Random 2D plane. I would like to find the number of points in a circle within this plane. Can anybody helps in solving the problem?

Regards

Comment: Are these infinitely-many points; uncountably-infinite?

Comment: Are you also referring to any specific , predefined circle, or do you want to find the circle with the largest expected number of points?

Comment: The circle is predefined and there is no restriction of finding the circle with largest number of points.

Comment: Please do not use the tag (poisson-geometry) for questions related to Poisson processes. The two are unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

That completely depends on the distribution of the points. In general, nothing can be said. For example, if the distribution of points is gaussian with mean $(0,0)$, then there will be much more points in the circle with center $(0,0)$ and radius $1$ than in the circle with center $(100000,100000)$ and radius $1$.

Comment: The distribution of points is Uniform across the space.

Comment: No it's not. There is no uniform distribution of points over the whole $\mathbb R^2.$

Comment: Actually, i am giving some more information that as each point is equally likely, therefore, the points are distributed uniformly across the space.

Comment: Well, no. Each point *cannot* be equally likely, that is my point. There exists no random distribution over $\mathbb R^2$ such that the probability of the random variable being in the set $S$ depends only on the area of the set $S$.

Comment: Presumably what is meant is that the points form a spatial Poisson process with uniform density.  The number of points in a region of finite area is then a Poisson random variable with mean the product of area and density.

Comment: @RobertIsrael area of what, if I may ask?

Comment: Area of the region.

Comment: @And $\mathbb R^2$ is an region of finite area?